# Java PathMatcher: GLOB patterns are inconsistent on UNIX/Windows

Tags: java, unix, design-patterns, nio, glob

**Background**:

I was writing a filewalker that starts at a specific folder and walks through each subfolder and its contents. Each time a directory or file is visited I compare the path to a PathMatcher containing a glob pattern (directories matched on path, files matched on extension). If it matched the pattern I would add it to a list for later use. This is so that I can build a filtered list based on a GLOB pattern. I wrote this on Unix (mac) and it seemed to work fine. When I tested it on Windows I got 0 results.

```
    Filter(String dirPattern, String extensionPattern) {
        dirMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(
                "glob:" + dirPattern);
        extensionMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(
                "glob:" + extensionPattern);
    }
```

**Problem:**

Take these GLOB patterns for example

Directory pattern:

```
**/{foo/bar,foo/baz/,fizz/buzz/fizzbuzz}
```

Would work fine on UNIX but not on Windows. Now I've read that the JVM shouldn't have trouble interpreting '/' as a valid file seperator for both platforms but nonetheless I tried changing it to a Windows style path.

```
**\{foo\bar,foo\baz\,fizz\buzz\fizzbuzz}
```

Needs some escaping for java:

```
**\\{foo\\bar,foo\\baz\\,fizz\\buzz\\fizzbuzz}
```

But this **still** wont match anything...

I even tried doing an OS check and replacing the '/' with Java File.seperator.

```
    if (OSUtil.getCurrentOS() == OS.Windows) {
            dirPattern = dirPattern.replace("/", File.separator);
            extensionPattern = extensionPattern
                    .replace("/", File.separator);
        }
```

It seems like the file seperators between the brackets are interpreted and correct but the first slash needs to be Windows style. At this point I'm not sure what is happening. Is there anyone that can shed some light on this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was having some problems also with the PathMatcher on Windows.  I had to use "/" as a separator (i.e. same as Unix), and then it seemed to work fine.  I tried a similar pattern as you did, i.e. `**/{dir1/dir2/dir3/, dir4}` and it matched as expected.  What I see in the debugger, is that under the hood,  it reversed the slashes (to match Windows separator) and it gets converted to a RegExp pattern.  So it appears to be doing a Regular Expression match against the path string.